# GoSublime/GoLint caching Import Packages?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter, gosublime, golint

Does SublimeText 3 / GoSublime have some type of caching of `Go` import packages?  If so, how do I clear it on demand?

I ask because while writing a custom package that is under Github source control, it works until I refactor a func or struct.  Then, back at my main app (of where I import this package) it lights up like a Christmas tree when I start using the new methods.

GoSublime (or GoLint?) does not pick up the refactored func changes, and everything shows as an error.  But yet, I can go to a prompt and run `go build` and `go test` just fine - the Go tool works fine.

The only thing I have been able to nail down is after about 24 hours it seems to work?

```
OSX 10.9
SublimeText 3
GoSublime
sublimelint **<- DO I NEED THIS?  SAYS IT IS FOR HIGHLIGHTING**
SublimeLinter
SublimeLinter-contrib-GoLint
SublimeLinter-contril-GoType
(and a few other packages)
```

I'm a SublimeText novice; but, I believe I have everything linked up and the required packages installed.  Sublime's console shows no errors in the Linters (says it find gotype and golint).

`SublimeLinter: gotype activated: /Users/user1/go/bin/gotype 
SublimeLinter: golint activated: /Users/user1/go/bin/golint`

Things work beautifully within the package itself.  It's not only my remote app.  In my package, I have an "/examples" directory of tests that doesn't even pick up the changes in the root package.  But again, the actual `Go` tool does and builds and runs all tests using the new refactored code.

It is GoSublime/GoLint that is caching the import's schema/package details.  How do I clear that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coming back to answer myself this after 5 months of no answers...

@dave-cheney himself replied to a Google Groups message I posted on this subject:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/N3xB6PGs3wo

Resolution:

- That code, even one-off tooling for other projects, must live in your `$GOPATH/src`.    I have changed all projects to be in the `$GOPATH/src/privatedomain/etc`, and updated build scripts to just deploy the executable to those other repos (and commit them).  Learn to work with the tools, not fight it.  :)
- You need to run `go install [package]` on those locally developed packages for their changes to show up immediately in your current Sublime project.  There is still a long day-long delay that happens though if you don't run go install that the changes are picked up in other tools/packages within Sublime.  "go install" works to get around this every time so no big deal (*see next bullet point).
- In Sublime, I often run `go install [package]` and then close/re-open the current file I am working on to pick up the changes.

Note that you don't have to be online for the `go install [package]` - if the package is local that is (e.g. in development).  So, this was the answer to my environment since I do a lot of development offline (commuting).